# access violation while stereo calibration?

Tags: c++, opencv, access-violation, camera-calibration

Iam getting access violation error while I am performing debugging in stereo calibration

code is as follows

```
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++){    
                       cornersR[j]=cvPoint2D32f(cornersRp[j].x,cornersRp[j].y);
                       cornersL[j]=cvPoint2D32f(cornersLp[j].x,cornersLp[j].y);
                       }
```

these are initialized as follows,n is a fixed integer

```
           CvPoint2D32f* cornersRp = new CvPoint2D32f[ n ];
           CvPoint2D32f* cornersLp = new CvPoint2D32f[ n ];
           vector<CvPoint2D32f> cornersR;
           vector<CvPoint2D32f> cornersL;
```

please help me out.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use `vector[]` you have to ensure that the `vector` has an element at that index. In this case, both the vectors are empty resulting in the access violation.

Change the declarations to:

```
vector<CvPoint2D32f> cornersR(n);
vector<CvPoint2D32f> cornersL(n);
```

which will populate the `vectors` with `n` default constructed instances of `CvPoint2D32f`.

If there is no default constructor for `CvPoint2D32f` you could either:

```
vector<CvPoint2D32f> cornersR(n, CvPoint2D32f(1,1));
vector<CvPoint2D32f> cornersL(n, CvPoint2D32f(1,1));
```

which would populate the vectors with copies of the second argument, or use [`vector::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) instead of `vector::operator[]` and without specifying an initial size for the vector:

```
vector<CvPoint2D32f> cornersR;
vector<CvPoint2D32f> cornersL;

cornersR.push_back(cvPoint2D32f(cornersRp[j].x,cornersRp[j].y));
```